# Error canvas parallax fondo pixel

Tags: javascript, canvas, game, parallax

Estoy creando un fondo parallax en canvas con JavaScript con movimiento en x, que contiene varias imágenes de 1920x1080 el cual tiene movimiento de izquierda a derecha y en reversa

Tengo el siguiente código JavaScript:

layer.js

```
export class Layer {
    constructor({ layer_path, layer_max, layer_height, layer_reverse, layer_speed }) {
        this.layers = []

        for (let i = 0; i < layer_max; i++) {
            let layer_image_count = i <= 9 ? `0${i}` : `${i}`
            let layer_speed_modifier = i < 9 ? `0.0${i + 1}` : `0.${i + 1}`
            let layer_image = new Image()

            layer_image.src = `${layer_path}/layer_${layer_image_count}.png`

            let layer_y = 0
            let layer_x = 0
            let layer_width = layer_image.width
            layer_speed_modifier = layer_reverse ? `-${layer_speed_modifier}` : layer_speed_modifier
            let layer_frame_init = 0

            this.layers.push({
                layer_image,
                layer_x,
                layer_y,
                layer_width,
                layer_height,
                layer_reverse,
                layer_speed_modifier,
                layer_speed,
                layer_frame_init
            })
        }
    }

    update() {
        for (let layer of this.layers) {
            layer.speed = layer.layer_speed * layer.layer_speed_modifier
            layer.layer_x = (layer.layer_frame_init * layer.speed) % layer.layer_width
            layer.layer_frame_init--
        }
    }

    draw({ ctx }) {
        for (let layer of this.layers) {
            ctx.drawImage(layer.layer_image, layer.layer_x, layer.layer_y, layer.layer_width, layer.layer_height)
            ctx.drawImage(layer.layer_image, layer.layer_reverse ? layer.layer_x - layer.layer_width : layer.layer_x + layer.layer_width, layer.layer_y, layer.layer_width, layer.layer_height)
        }
    }
}
```

main.js

```
const layer_path = "/assets/img/layer"
const layer_max = 12
const layer_height = canvas_height
const layer_reverse = true
const layer_speed = 50
const layer_1 = new Layer({ layer_path, layer_max, layer_height, layer_reverse, layer_speed })

const animate = async () => {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas_width, canvas_height)

    layer_1.update()
    layer_1.draw({ ctx })
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}
await animate()
```

El error es que cuando en layer_reverse coloco true, se muestra una línea vertical en la animación, la cual se mueve lentamente de izquierda a derecha hasta que desaparece y no se muestra más y cuando coloco false todo funciona bien

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan ayudarme Bendiciones.

Comment: ¿Pasa con cualquier asset que uses de fondo?

Comment: @PabloLozano Si efectivamente con cualquier cantidad de fondos destinados para un parallax en x

Answer (score 1):

Conseguí la solución y la dejo para el que pueda necesitarlo, tuve que modificar mucho el código pero así funciona mejor:

> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/main.css" />
    <script defer type="module" src="/assets/js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

> main.css / CSS moderno no es SCSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    list-style: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;

    &::before,
    &::after {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
}

body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #222;
    height: 100dvh;
}

canvas {
    background-color: #111;
}
```

> config.json

```
{
    "layer_states": [
        {
            "image": "/assets/img/layer/layer_00.png",
            "reverse": false,
            "speed": "0.00"
        },
        {
            "image": "/assets/img/layer/layer_01.png",
            "reverse": false,
            "speed": "0.01"
        },
        {
            "image": "/assets/img/layer/layer_02.png",
            "reverse": false,
            "speed": "0.02"
        },
        {
            "image": "/assets/img/layer/layer_03.png",
            "reverse": false,
            "speed": "0.03"
        },
        {
            "image": "/assets/img/layer/layer_04.png",
            "reverse": false,
            "speed": "0.04"
        },
        {
            "image": "/assets/img/layer/layer_05.png",
            "reverse": false,
            "speed": "0.05"
        },
        {
            "image": "/assets/img/layer/layer_06.png",
            "reverse": false,
            "speed": "0.06"
        },
        {
            "image": "/assets/img/layer/layer_07.png",
            "reverse": false,
            "speed": "0.07"
        },
        {
            "image": "/assets/img/layer/layer_08.png",
            "reverse": false,
            "speed": "0.08"
        },
        {
            "image": "/assets/img/layer/layer_09.png",
            "reverse": false,
            "speed": "0.09"
        },
        {
            "image": "/assets/img/layer/layer_10.png",
            "reverse": false,
            "speed": "0.10"
        },
        {
            "image": "/assets/img/layer/layer_11.png",
            "reverse": false,
            "speed": "0.11"
        }
     ],
    "layer_speed": 50
}
```

> init.js

```
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas")

export const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
export const canvas_width = (canvas_width = 64 * 16)
export const canvas_height = (canvas_height = 64 * 9)

ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false
```

> layer.js

```
export class Layer {
    constructor({ states, height, speed }) {
        this.layers = []

        for (let i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
            let image = new Image()

            image.src = states[i].image

            let reverse = states[i].reverse
            let y = 0
            let x = 0
            let width = image.width
            let frame_init = 0
            let speed_modifier = states[i].speed

            speed_modifier = reverse ? `-${speed_modifier}` : speed_modifier

            this.layers.push({
                image,
                x,
                y,
                width,
                height,
                reverse,
                speed_modifier,
                speed,
                frame_init
            })
        }
    }

    update() {
        for (let layer of this.layers) {
            layer.frame_speed = layer.speed * layer.speed_modifier
            layer.x = (layer.frame_init * layer.frame_speed) % layer.width
            layer.frame_init--
        }
    }

    draw({ ctx }) {
        for (let layer of this.layers) {
            ctx.drawImage(layer.image, layer.x, layer.y, layer.width, layer.height)
            ctx.drawImage(layer.image, layer.reverse ? layer.x - layer.width : layer.x + layer.width, layer.y, layer.width, layer.height)
        }
    }
}
```

> main.js

```
import _c from "/config/config.json" assert { type: "json" }
import { ctx, canvas_width, canvas_height } from "/assets/js/modules/init.js"
import { Layer } from "/assets/js/modules/layer.js"

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => {

    /* LAYER */
    const layer_1 = new Layer({ states: _c.layer_states, height: canvas_height, speed: _c.layer_speed })

    const animate = async () => {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas_width, canvas_height)

        /* LAYER */
        layer_1.update()
        layer_1.draw({ ctx })

        requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    }
    await animate()
})
```

> Imágenes: https://digitalmoons.itch.io/parallax-forest-background

Ya no da el error de la línea de un pixelada.